# Semi-Transparent Circle Overlay on Map

Tags: tomtom

I am trying to add a semi-transparent circle with a radius of (e.g.) 10 kilometers on a TomTom map.

Ideally the map zooms to a zoom factor to fit the circle perfectly in...

Anyone has a working code example?
Unfortunately the TomTom SDK documentation doesn't really help here...

```
<script>
    // Define your product name and version
    tomtom.setProductInfo('myApp', '4.44.7');
    var markerOptions = {
    icon: tomtom.L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'images/marker.png',
        iconSize: [30, 34],
        iconAnchor: [15, 34]
            })
        };
    var map = tomtom.map('map', {
    key: 'mykey',
    basePath: 'C:\jssdk-examples-latest-examples'
});
    tomtom.L.marker([48.78270899, 9.182864184], markerOptions).addTo(map);

    map.setView([48.78270899, 9.182864184], 9);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

TomTom SDK for Web is based on Leaflet.
If you are using circle class then you can get it's bounds with getBounds() and use them in fitBounds().
See the docs [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html)

And tutorial how to create a circle [here](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/)